# Zurb Foundation 4 Section collapsing

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

Trying to implement a section with Zurb Foundation 4.3.2. I've made sure to include the right couple of js and css files, and initialize foundation in the js script, but the section continues to collapse all the content and buttons together. The first section/tab doesn't show up either.

**EDIT:** Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanova/R2SdH/ (my first, so if I performed some kind of worst practice, let me know)

After making the JSFiddle, I realized that it's working correctly on smaller dpi screens (it looks alright in the small area JSFiddle provides, even if clicking the tabs isn't working - I checked with my actual code and making the browser window smaller switches the section to Accordion and it works great). So it seems that it's only on the larger screen sizes when it reverts to Tabs is when the section collapses and doesn't work.

Any ideas on what's going wrong? Thanks guys.

```
        <!-- foundation zurb -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/foundation.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/normalize.css">

        <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
        <script src='../../js/vendor/jquery.js'></script>
        <!-- zurb foundation -->
        <script src="../../js/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).foundation();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='small-12 columns'>
        123 Street Name <br /> City, ST Zip <br />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='large-8 columns'>
        <div class="section-container auto" data-section data-section-resized>
            <section class="active">
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Details</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content>
                    <p>Things like Comments, Area, Use Type, Current Use, Sqft, Taxes, Value, Status</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Improvements</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content>
                    <p>Any improvements data</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel3">Mortgage</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content>
                    <p>Mortage data.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel4">Lease</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content>
                    <p>Lease data.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel5">Lien</a></p>
                <div class="content" data-section-content>
                    <p>Lien data.</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class='large-4 columns'>
        Map Goes Here
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='large-12 columns'>
        Related people
    </div>
   </div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='large-12 columns'>
        Related properties
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone willing to check this out for you would first need to create a working jsfiddle of your code. Chances are, this won't happen. If you create one yourself, you'll see some comments/answers pretty quick.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a JSFiddle that illustrates the problem if you give the results box enough room (make it bigger).

Comment: Hard to confirm this with complete certainty using jsfiddle, but it looks like your javascript isn't loading properly. Check the console when your actual site (not jsfiddle) loads, I'm guessing something is out of order.

Comment: I took the HTML from their example page on sections and inserted it into my page, and it worked. The only real differences I can see between my code and theirs is styling at the element level. Perhaps the JS is supposed to add CSS styling and for some reason it just doesn't get run? The console doesn't show any warnings/errors with just my code though.

Comment: I've lost entire days on stuff like this lol. Keep comparing your code to theirs, bearing in mind that some of those classes and data attributes are supposed to be added and removed by Foundation's scripts. Make sure your sections are expanding when clicked, as they weren't doing that on your fiddle, even in the smaller layout.

Comment: I'd also recommend deleting this question, as it's unanswered status will continue to attract people looking to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still need help though. I have no idea why the JS is running correctly for smaller window sizes but not for bigger ones. I directed a question at the Zurb guys on Twitter, maybe they will help. I've tried looking at and stepping through the foundation js but it's beyond my ability to really figure out what's going on.

Comment: Your earlier comment seemed to indicate that progress has been made when you used the code from Zurb's docs - what has changed?

Comment: Well what actually happened I suppose was I copied the DOM from their page onto mine, and since it was already rendered by the foundation JS of course it worked. It left me with the conundrum of why small windows were getting rendered correctly and not larger windows. All copying their code into my page did was tell me what kind of styling/attributes the JS was supposed to render mine with, but since it was dynamic I didn't want to just hard code that stuff into mine. I wanted to find the right way to get the JS working. Thanks for the prodding though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I figured it out. I downloaded the source code from their Section page and started inserting my code trying to get it to work. The reason I got here in the first place was because my section disappeared at one point and another stackoverflow answer said just add "data-section-resized" to the section container div. Well, don't. That got it back to being invisible. I had removed some js from my header to try to closer match theirs, and it was a mistake. This is what my section and header looks like now:

Header:

```
    <!-- foundation zurb -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/general_foundicons.css">
    <!-- zurb foundation -->
    <script src="../../js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Supposedly, foundation.min.js includes all the others like section. I can confirm if you try to replace foundation.js and foundation.section.js with foundation.min.js it will not work. If you keep section.js and change to foundation.js to foundation.min.js it will not work. You have to have foundation.js and foundation.section.js.

Section:

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='large-8 columns'>
    <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
        <section class="active">
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Details</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Things like Comments, Area, Use Type, Current Use, Sqft, Taxes, Value, Status</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Improvements</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Any improvements data</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel3">Mortgage</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Mortage data.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel4">Lease</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Lease data.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel5">Lien</a></p>
            <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <p>Lien data.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='large-4 columns'>
    Map Goes Here
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Strange...foundation.min.js should work. Are you on Foundation 4.3.2?

Comment: Yep, opened up foundation.min.js just to confirm and it shows 4.3.2